# Write a pattern to select all URIs from a GCS bucket while creating an External Table in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, glob, external-tables

Is there a way to create an external table using a pattern of URIs of stored CSV files in a GCS bucket?

For instance:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sampledataset.sample_table
OPTIONS(
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://bucketname/dir1/Sample_*.csv']
);
```

Can I create an external table for all CSV files that begin with "Sample_"?

Comment: Do you have any problem with your DDL ? or you're considering ones stored in another directory like `/dir2/Sample_*.csv` ?

Comment: The directory in question will receive multiple files with different names but the same pattern, along with another directory expected to have similar files and the same pattern for names too. These files would be changing with time.

Comment: You can add more paths in `uris` option which is not flexible depending on the number of folders you should consider. And maybe you can apply a regular expression pattern  to `_FILE_NAME` pseudo column to filter out files in a query level, but I think this also has some limitation.